# how to loop through each excel sheet name

Tags: python, excel, formatting

I am trying to apply conditional formatting to my workbook which has multiple sheets but the below code will not work. I need a loop which will go through each sheet but when I run it, it doesnt recongise sheet 1.

```
#Apply % bars to the column.
sheet_name = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4']

for n in range(0,len(sheet_name),1):
    ws = writer.sheets[sheet_name[n]]
    ws.conditional_format('H2:H100', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                       #'bar_solid': True})

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `writer.save()` inside the loop,

Comment: still says it doesn't recgonsie sheet 1

Comment: the indentation suggestion makes no sense. It needs more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The OP (*debugging-mode*) script produces below print result:

```
sheet_name = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4']

# code OP.

for n in range(0,len(sheet_name),1):

    print (n)                         # debugging to see what happens here.
    x = [sheet_name[n]]
    print (x)                         # and see what this does.

... snippet code....
```

And prints the following:

```
0                # n0
['sheet1']       # x
1                # n1
['sheet2']       # x
2                # n2
['sheet3']       # x
3                # n3
['sheet4']       # x
```

There are two flavors to get your sheetname and sheetnumber correct for input in the `ws = ..code`:

```
sheet_name = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4']

for sheet in sheet_name:

    # option 1 to get sheetname and sheet number

    sheetname = ''
    sheetnumber = ''
    for x in sheet:
        print (x)                  # opt.1 print 1
        if x is not int:
            sheetname +=x
        else:
            sheetnumber + x

    print (sheetname, sheetnumber) # opt.1 print 2


    # option 2 to get sheetname and sheet number

    name, value = sheet[0:5], sheet[5:]
    print (name, value)

    # ... your code ...continues here with linked option 1 or 2.

#    ws = writer.sheets[sheet_name[n]]
#    ws.conditional_format('H2:H100', {'type': 'data_bar',
                                       #'bar_solid': True})

#writer.save()   # <-- check if...
```

...user [Carsten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11170205/carsten) is correct about indentation for this!!

The printed result from both options:

```
s         # opt.1 ..print 1
h
e
e
t
1
sheet1    # opt.1 ..print 2 
sheet 1   # opt.2
s         # opt.1 ..print 1
h
e
e
t
2
sheet2    # opt.1 ..print 2 
sheet 2   # opt.2

...snippet ...
```

Comment: this still doesnt work im afraid. now i get an error saying 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'conditional_format'.

Comment: ***this still doesn't work I'm afraid***. What does not work? Which add-on are you using (`xlwt`, `openpyxl`, `xlsxwriter` or something else)? Also add the excel-file creation (version/type) and which solution I proposed to iter through the excel-sheetname-list did you choose? Update your question to include this. Without it too many possibilities. IT sounds like a follow-up error you previously could not encounter.

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filepath, engine='xlsxwriter'). then i have the sheet_name variable etc and i used option 1. the excel file is an xlsx type